# Switch Case help C

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am attempting to check string letters against another let of letters, checking the first letter in userword[k] against all the letters in letterstest[t] and if they match switching that matching letter of letterstest[t] with 0 so it cannot be matched again. Where I am confused on is inside the switch(){ and what exactly would work. Is there a case: what can switch the letters of the strings?

```
for (k = 0; k<wordsize; k++){
    for(t=0; t<8, t++){
        if (userword[k] != letterstest[t]) 
            return 0;

        if (userword[k] == letterstest[t]){    
            switch (letterstest[t]){

                    //unsure what case would work here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My first if statement seems a little off to me. I need it to return 0 if the letter is not anywhere inside letterstest. Looks like I've got it only checking that current letter

Comment: `//unsure what case would work here` - me too, because I have no idea what type `letterstest` actually is.  Please post its declaration (and initialization)

Comment: Sorry about that, `char letterstest[8];`

Comment: Really suggest you try rephrasing your problem. I've read it three times, each time thinking I've got it, then when I look at the specific question I realize I don't have a clue. If you find a match and just want letterstest[t]='0', why not just assign it that way (assuming its a char * or char[]).... Just need a better problem description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `switch` is. `switch` is a selection structure, like `if`/`else`. For example, these two code-snippets are (generally) equivalent:

```
if(a == 0)
    printf("%s\n", "zero");
else if(a == 1)
    printf("%s\n", "one");
else if(a == 2)
    printf("%s\n", "two");
else
    printf("%s\n", "invalid");

switch(a)
{
    case 0:
        printf("%s\n", "zero");
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("%s\n", "one");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("%s\n", "two");
        break;
    default:
        printf("%s\n", "invalid");
}
```

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but when you write "if they match switching that matching letter of letterstest[t] with 0 so it cannot be matched again", it sounds like you mean this:

```
    if (userword[k] == letterstest[t]){
        letterstest[t] = '\0';
    }
```

---

**Edited to add:** O.K., I *think* I now understand what you're trying to do:

- you want to confirm that every character between `userword[0]` and `userword[wordsize-1]` appears somewhere between `letterstest[0]` and `letterstest[7]`.
- if a given character appears multiple times between `userword[0]` and `userword[wordsize-1]`, then it must appear at least as many times between `letterstest[0]` and `letterstest[7]`. That is — a character between `letterstest[0]` and `letterstest[7]` can only count once.
- you're O.K. with changing what characters appear between `letterstest[0]` and `letterstest[7]`, as long as the final answer is correct; that is, you don't need to preserve the contents of `letterstest`.
- the character `'\0'` does not occur anywhere between `userword[0]` and `userword[wordsize-1]`, so can be used as a "dummy" value meaning "not a match".

Is that correct?

If so, then you can write:

```
for(k = 0; k < wordsize; k++) {
    for(t = 0; t < 8; t++) {
        if(userword[k] == letterstest[t]) {
            letterstest[t] = '\0'; /* don't let letterstest[t] count again */
            break; /* O.K., we've matched userword[k], we can move on */
        }
    }
    if(t == 8) /* we reached letterstest[8] without finding a match */
        return 0;
}
return 1; /* we found a match for each character */
```

Comment: Ah that makes way more sense to me know. I have a large portion of this program that uses switch and I should have known it wouldn't work here. Thank you for the help

Comment: ruakh you have an idea for an answer to my other question in the comment above?  
My first if statement seems a little off to me. I need it to return 0 if the letter is not anywhere inside letterstest. Looks like I've got it only checking that current letter.

Comment: That works great! Thanks so much that's exactly what was in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first you can use any functions to match character or string in other...
(If you want not use "for" loops)

In linux use "man" command on (functions):

- strchr
- strstr
- index
- rindex
  ...

After if you want switch a char you can use the ascii code of char (http://www.table-ascii.com/), or directly the char...

Example if you want check the 'A' character you can make that:

```
// Char Method
switch (letterstest[t]){
    case 'A':
        printf("A Detected !\n");
        break;
}

// Or Use The ASCII Code Method
switch (letterstest[t]){
    case 65:
        printf("A Detected !\n");
        break;
}
```

Example if you want check the '0' character (the number) you can make that:

```
// Char Method
switch (letterstest[t]){
    case '0':
        printf("0 Detected !\n");
        break;
}

// Or Use The ASCII Code Method
switch (letterstest[t]){
    case 48:
        printf("0 Detected !\n");
        break;
}
```

Example if you want check the 0 character ('\0' NUL) you can make that:

```
// Char Method
switch (letterstest[t]){
    case '\0':
        printf("NUL Detected !\n");
        break;
}

// Or Use The ASCII Code Method
switch (letterstest[t]){
    case 0:
        printf("NUL Detected !\n");
        break;
}
```